# After dragging a file on exe, ifstream fails to open file

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, ifstream

I have have the following problem:

When I drag and drop a file to my tool (exe) when `ifstream` fails to open the file.
If I give it manually though the console it works!
I don't get where the diffenence is, because I am cutting the path and passing just the filename.
Have a look at the code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
if (argc < 2) {
    cout
        << "ERROR: Wrong amount of arguments! Give at least one argument ...\n"
        << endl;
    cout << "\n" << "Programm finished...\n\n" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    exit(1);
    return 0;
    }

    vector<string> files;

   for (int g = 1; g < argc; g++) {
      string s = argv[g];
      cout<<"parameter at: " << g << " = " << argv[g] << "\n" << endl;

      string filename = "";
      int pos = s.find_last_of("\\", s.size());

      if (pos != -1) {
          filename.append(s.substr(pos + 1));
//         cout<<" cutted path: " << s.substr(0,s.size()-filename.size()) << endl;

//            cout << "argv[1] " << argv[1] << endl;
          cout << "\n filename: " << filename << "\t pos: " << pos << endl;
          files.push_back(filename);

          }
      files.push_back(s);
      }


  for (unsigned int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++)
      {
      cout << "files.at( " << k << " ): " << files.at(k).c_str() << endl;
      Converter a(files.at(k).c_str());
      a.getCommandsFromCSV();
      a.saveConvertedFile();
      }

  cout << "\n" << "Programm finished...\n\n" << endl;

  cin.ignore();

  return 0;
}
```

It fails already on the constructor:

```
Converter::Converter(const char* file) {
  filename = file;
  myfile.open(filename.c_str(), ios_base::in);

  cout << (myfile ? "open successful on constructor " : "some error on constructor");
  cin.ignore();

  trace_raw = "";
}
```

You have any idea why?

---

**UPDATE:**
The file as parameter works now. The solution was to leave the full path.
Anyway I have the same error on a hard coded file. I thought it may be the same that's why I added `.\` at the beginning of the file name... without success.
The code:

```
void GenericCommandConverter::getATCommandsFromCSV() {

  cout << "\t| +++++++++++getATCommandsFromCSV() started+++++++++++++ |"
    << endl;

 /*
  * CSV file name is hardcoded
  */
  string filename_csv = ".\\test.csv";
  string commands = "";
  int pos_start = 0;
  int pos_end = 0; // "|"
  int substrLength = 0;
  int separator_count = 0;

  char c;

  vector<string> lines;
  vector<string> commandList;
  vector<vector<string> > linesSeparated;


  ifstream csvFile;
  csvFile.open(filename_csv.c_str(), ios_base::in);

  cout << (myfile ? "open successful on getATCommandsFromCSV " : "some error on   getATCommandsFromCSV ");
  cin.ignore();  
      ...
```

**UPDATE2:**
The solution was: on dropping a file to the exe, the "root" folder changes to the one where the dropped file comes from. Giving the hardcoded file the path from the *.exe solved it!

Comment: Guess: the shell might still have a lock on the file? You could try adding a delay before you open the file (not a good solution! although delay + retry a few times might be OK) or open the file specifying read lock only - not sure how to do this through ifstream.

Comment: you could print the value of `file` to see if the value is the same in both situations

Comment: @ Kiril Kirov did, filename is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing your current directory is wrong. Don't cut the path off. Anyway you should do error checking / debugging to see why it couldn't open the file. Diligent debugging is essential for solving problems without having to make blind guesses.

Comment: Unfortunately, ifstream provides no way to see why the open failed.

Comment: practically speaking, you can still usually use `errno()` for ifstream. At very least though I was more referring to just using a debugger - in which case he should be able to see `@err` in the watch window (in VS) or step through to the system call.

Comment: Ok now this file works. You are right, I need the full path.  
I have another file csv which is hardcoded filename, now this one fails. I tried to put ".\" before. Doesn't help. Same again, lauching though console works. Any Ideas? Same problem

Comment: Make sure you know the current directory in each case. Log it, verify it. When you drop the file, the current directory is set to the one of the dropped file.

Comment: @Suma thanks! That was the point. I didn't know it changes the directory on dropping a file! Would give u +1 if I could